# connection can not be established between schema registry docker and kafka broker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running a schema registry server using the following code:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
    schema-registry:
        container_name: schema-registry
        image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.0
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./config:/tmp/conf
        ports:
          - "8081:8081"
        environment:
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=localhost:9092
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC=_schemas
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS=http://0.0.0.0:8081
          - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG=true
        ulimits:
          nproc: 65535
          nofile:
            soft: 65535
            hard: 65535
        logging:
            driver: json-file
            options:
              max-size: "100m"
              max-file: "3"
```

After deploying it with a docker compose up I get the following error :

```
[kafka-admin-client-thread | adminclient-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Kafka is running locally (it is not running in docker), by the way , the kafka server properties has the following conf:

broker.id=0

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/2568649 apply here?

Comment: Seems you'll need to do more research about how docker networking works. `localhost` is the container itself, not another service, and especially not the host machine

Answer (score 1):

As Chris says, you need to [connect your Schema Registry Docker container to the local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/2568649). Either that, or run Kafka in Docker too (or run Schema Registry locally as well e.g. from the [tarbar available as part of Confluent Platform](https://www.confluent.io/download/#confluent-platform))